# GWT Interview Questions

Tags: gwt

Can anyone suggest me some nice questions which could be asked for a GWT Developer? I am looking for a GWT developer and I am not sure what questions can be asked.

I am planning to ask questions on GWT-RPC, GWT Widgets, etc., but I am not sure what exactlty I need to ask.

Comment: Hi Jason, I recommend you to try skills testing solutions instead of spending your precious time. LuGo-Test.com covers GWT and charge 10$ per test. I am sure there are other good platforms for skills testing.

Answer (score 6):

Some GWT-specific interview questions off the top of my head:

- What are some advantages for the Model-View-Presenter pattern?
- How can you test a GWT application?
- Describe what a GWT generator does
- What are some benefits of using `CssResource`, `ImageResource`, `TextResource`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the questions.I would definetly appreciate some more questions

Answer (score 4):

Some more basic questions to begin with:

- How does GWT app work? (compiling to JavaScript, cross-browser support, bootstrapping script, etc.)
- When would you NOT use GWT? (rather general and open-ended question, but it demonstrates if developer is really into this technology) Follow-up question: What GWT alternatives would you consider?
- What 3d party libraries have used with GWT? Which libraries would you recommend? Why?
- Describe server-side development with GWT.
- Did you use DI framework with GWT?
- What does make MVP better fit for GWT than general MVC?

Answer (score 2):

Also, off the top of my head:

- Serialization and Un-serialization. What is required of a user defined class for it to be serializable?
- Event handling. Describe how an event bus is used and implemented.
- Describe how one module can inherit or use members from another GWT module.

Answer (score 2):

Likewise, if you want to ask a more specific question to see how the developer would tackle a certain task, consider something like this:

Lets say a designer sends you a html/css design for a popup on the site. Popup is used to input some data. You have to implement such a popup in gwt. The html/css of the result popup has to look exactly like the one provided. How would you go about implementing this. Which widgets could you use, and which you cannot? Are there more approaches to this problem? What are the problems that might arise, and which parts of this design could be problematic for gwt?

This is the example html code:

```
<div id="popup" class="our-popup">
  <div class="popup-body">
        <div class="header">
         <div class="content">
             <form action="#">
                 <fieldset>
                        <label for="f1">field1:</label><input type="text" id="f1" tabindex="11" /><br />
                        <label for="f2">field2:</label><input type="text" id="f2" tabindex="12" /><br />
                        <label for="f3">field3:</label><input type="text" id="f3" tabindex="13" /><br />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="sumbit" tabindex="20" />
                 </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

After you have the custom popup widget, how would you plug it in to your application? How would you get the input to your service layer?

The point of this question is not for the developer to solve it right away, but to test the way of thinking and the way of handling and solving problems in this domain.